# How can use instance method before create instance of class?

Tags: java, android, instance, instance-methods

i have this code :

```
public class NumbersFragment extends Fragment {

    /** Handles playback of all the sound files */
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

      private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            // Now that the sound file has finished playing, release the media player resources.
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }
    };


 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list, container, false);

        // Create a list of words
        final ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
        words.add(new Word(R.string.number_one, 
                R.drawable.number_one, R.raw.number_one));
        words.add(new Word(R.string.number_two, 
                R.drawable.number_two, R.raw.number_two));
        words.add(new Word(R.string.number_three, 
                R.drawable.number_three, R.raw.number_three));
        words.add(new Word(R.string.number_four, 
                R.drawable.number_four, R.raw.number_four));
        words.add(new Word(R.string.number_five, 
                R.drawable.number_five, R.raw.number_five));
        words.add(new Word(R.string.number_six, 
                R.drawable.number_six, R.raw.number_six));
        words.add(new Word(R.string.number_seven, 
                R.drawable.number_seven, R.raw.number_seven));
        words.add(new Word(R.string.number_eight, 
                R.drawable.number_eight, R.raw.number_eight));
        words.add(new Word(R.string.number_nine, 
                R.drawable.number_nine, R.raw.number_nine));
        words.add(new Word(R.string.number_ten, 
                R.drawable.number_ten, R.raw.number_ten));

        // Create an {@link WordAdapter}, whose data source is a list of {@link Word}s. The
        // adapter knows how to create list items for each item in the list.
        WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(getActivity(), words, R.color.category_numbers);

        // Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
        // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
        // word_list.xml layout file.
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link WordAdapter} we created above, so that the
        // {@link ListView} will display list items for each {@link Word} in the list.
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set a click listener to play the audio when the list item is clicked on
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                // Release the media player if it currently exists because we are about to
                // play a different sound file
                releaseMediaPlayer();

                // Get the {@link Word} object at the given position the user clicked on
                Word word = words.get(position);

          // Create and setup the {@link MediaPlayer} for the audio resource associated
                    // with the current word
                 mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), word.getAudioResourceId());

                    // Start the audio file
                    mMediaPlayer.start();

                    // Setup a listener on the media player, so that we can stop and release the
                    // media player once the sound has finished playing.
                    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }


 private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        // If the media player is not null, then it may be currently playing a sound.
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            // Regardless of the current state of the media player, release its resources
            // because we no longer need it.
            mMediaPlayer.release();

            // Set the media player back to null. For our code, we've decided that
            // setting the media player to null is an easy way to tell that the media player
            // is not configured to play an audio file at the moment.
            mMediaPlayer = null;

            // Regardless of whether or not we were granted audio focus, abandon it. This also
            // unregisters the AudioFocusChangeListener so we don't get anymore callbacks.
            mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener);
        }
    }
```

if you have a look at code above you Notes that there is  `releaseMediaPlayer()` method and inside this method i called  `mMediaPlayer.release()` ,before create instance of `MediaPlayer` class i called  `releaseMediaPlayer()` , and code work there is no error , so how can this work calling instance method before create instance of class??

Comment: You have a `null` checking. Even if `mMediaPlaer` is not created when you call `releaseMediaPlayer()`, it won't crash because `mMediaPlayer.release()` won't be called.

Comment: no code work and there is no any error or problem

Answer (score 1):

From your code you check if mMediaplayer != null. If you have no instance of mediaplayer, then you won't pass if condition and mMediaPlayer.release() won't be executed.

```
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    // If the media player is not null, then it may be currently playing a sound.
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        // Regardless of the current state of the media player, release its resources
        // because we no longer need it.
        mMediaPlayer.release();

        // Set the media player back to null. For our code, we've decided that
        // setting the media player to null is an easy way to tell that the media player
        // is not configured to play an audio file at the moment.
        mMediaPlayer = null;

        // Regardless of whether or not we were granted audio focus, abandon it. This also
        // unregisters the AudioFocusChangeListener so we don't get anymore callbacks.
        mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener);
    }
```

Comment: so how can i call release(); method even there is no instance , for example if i want to call setText() method in TextView class i should hold reference of TextView in reference variable before i can use it's method, but in my example even mMediaPlayer = null i can call MediaPlayer methods there is any pattern here?

Comment: yes thank for alert me , but look at me question above can you answer me

Comment: @YazanKhateeb you ask how you can call an instance method before creating an instance.. you can't! ...your `mMediaPlayer` variable references nothing (is null) until you assign it to an instance, and the reason your code doesn't crash (as pointed out by this answer and other comments) is because you are explicitly checking to make sure its not `null`.

Comment: @YazanKhateeb sorry I think there is a language barrier :( I don't understand your question. There is no special case with MediaPlayer. If you declare a `TextView txtView;` but don't assign it to anything, then explicitly check to see if its null (`txtView != null`) and then inside that block try to call `setText` .. you will observe the same. There is no instance of TextView (its null), it will compile (no compile time error), and it runs (no runtime error thanks to the null check).

Comment: @trooper when i type TextView t; t=null , so when i write  "t." android studio show me all method in TextView class , so i do not want to create instance from class to display it's members !

Comment: to be clear, when you write `TextView t;` that is a variable declaration (there isn't an instance of TextView yet). Later when you write `t = ..` you are assigning an instance to the variable. ...but it sounds like you are describing intelisense (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion) which doesn't really have anything to do with that. Android Studio is performing a lookup on the API in order to suggest valid code - you don't need an actual instance to use it (only a declaration so it knows the type).

Comment: My suggestion is to get out of the habit of relying on intelisense to tell you about your code, and to get into the habit of reading the API yourself. For example, here's the documentation for TextView https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html, and for MediaPlayer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html